# Bash If statement to compare array's variables

Tags: bash

Try to figure out how to apply conditions to two variables, one of them read from file and stored into array.
Seems that the problem is the second variable, the one stored into array.

```
#!/bin/bash
#CHECKTIME


#GET TIME
IFS=- read -r DAY HOUR MINUTE < <(date +%u-%H-%M)
echo $DAY
echo $HOUR
echo $MINUTE

arr=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  arr+=("$line")
done < myFile.txt

echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}

if [ $DAY =  $arr[0]]
then
    echo "do event"

else
        echo "don't do event"
fi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for getting an element of an array is this:

```
${arr[0]}
```

Although that's not the only problem with your script. You could use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to debug the rest. To start, `[ $DAY =  $arr[0]]` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing zsh and bash syntax here. You `if` statement would be valid under zsh (although in zsh it should be `$arr[1]` instead of `$arr[0]`). In bash, you can do either

```
if [ "$DAY" = "${arr[0]}" ]
```

or (if you don't like quoting)

```
if [[ $DAY == ${arr[0]} ]]
```